# Sparse arrays and reduce in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sparse-array

One would think that in JavaScript:
`var array = [1,2,undefined,4];`
is the same as:

```
var array = [1,2];
array.length = 3;
array.push(4);
```

but it's not. This code shows it:

```
var array1 = [1,2];
array1.length = 3;
array1.push(4);

var array2 = [1,2,undefined,4];

traverseArray(array1);
traverseArray(array2);

function traverseArray(array) {
  console.log("trying: " + array);
  console.log("reduce:");
  array.reduce(function(prev, current, index, array) {
    if(current === undefined) {
      console.log("Found undefined");
    }
    console.log(index+": " +current);
  }, undefined);

  console.log("for loop:")
  for(var i=0;i < array.length;i++) {
    var current = array[i];
    console.log(i+": " +current);
  }
  console.log();
}
```

Output:

```
trying: 1,2,,4
reduce:
0: 1
1: 2
3: 4
for loop:
0: 1
1: 2
2: undefined
3: 4

trying: 1,2,,4
reduce:
0: 1
1: 2
Found undefined
2: undefined
3: 4
for loop:
0: 1
1: 2
2: undefined
3: 4
```

Why is undefined in array1 not the same as undefined in array2 and why does the for loop act the same but reduce does not?

Comment: The difference is that `[1,2,undefined,4]` has a property named `2` (with a value of `undefined`), while the other array does not have a property named `2`. There may be a duplicate somewhere with a good explanation.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) says: "reduce executes the callback function once for each element present in the array, excluding holes in the array"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array1` has three numerically-named properties: `0`, `1`, and `3`.

`array2` has four numerically-named properties: `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`. The value of the property named `2` happens to be `undefined`.

When you ask an object for the value of a property it doesn't have, the result is `undefined`.

In the `for` loop, you ask each array for the values of its properties named `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`. For `array1`, the property named `2` does not exist, so the property access produces `undefined`. For `array2`, the property *does* exist, but its value actually *is* `undefined`, so you get the same result.

On the other hand, `reduce` only operates on properties that actually exist. [From the ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.21), this is how `reduce` loops over arrays, using a counter `k`:

> 9. Repeat, while *k* < *len*
>
>    - Let *Pk* be ToString(*k*).
>    - Let *kPresent* be the result of calling the [[HasProperty]] internal method of *O* with argument *Pk*.
>    - If *kPresent* is true, then... [use the value at index k for the reduce call]

So, we can see that an index is only used if passes a [[HasProperty]] check. `array1` does not have a property named `2`, so that index is skipped.

Answer (score 3):

**apsillers** nailed it in the comments . . . the difference is that in `array2` you have actually assigned an `undefined` value to the 3rd element in the array (i.e., at index 2), where as, in `array1`, you have two elements initially, change the length property, and then add a third element in the forth position.

Here are the relevent sections from MDN that explains why the distinction is important:

- From the [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) on `Array.length`:

> When you extend an array by changing its length property, the number of actual elements does not increase; for example, if you set length to 3 when it is currently 2, the array still contains only 2 elements. Thus, the length property says nothing about the number of defined values in the array.

- From the [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) on `Array.push()`:

> The push method relies on a length property to determine where to start inserting the given values.

The key here, is really that the `length` property is really, simple a property that is in no way inherantly tied to the contents of the array.  It is simply because the various methods of `Array` also happen to maintain that property, as they "do their work", that I behaves as if it is.

So, as a result, in `array2`, the code is actually reporting back the `undefined` value that you assigned to `array2[2]`, whereas, with `array1`, the code is interpreting the absence of a value at `array1[2]` as `undefined`.